# The improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^n}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

\begin{array} { l } { \text { Let } \alpha , p \text { be real and } \alpha > 1 \text { , then } } \\ { \text { (1) if } p > 1 , \text { then } \int _ { - \infty } ^ { \infty } \frac { 1 } { | x | ^ { p \alpha} } d x < \infty } \\ { \text { (2) if } p > \frac { 1 } { \alpha } , \text { then } \int _ { - \infty } ^ { \infty } \frac { 1 } { | x | ^ { p \alpha} d x } < \infty } \\ { \text { (3) if } p < \frac { 1 } { \alpha } \text { , then } \int _ { - \infty } ^ { \infty } \frac { 1 } { \left.{ |x ^ {  } } \right| ^ { p \alpha} d x } < \infty } \\ { \text { (4) For any } p \in \mathbb { R } . \text { We have } \int _ { - \infty } ^ { \infty } \frac { 1 } { | x | ^ { p\alpha ^ { } } d x } = \infty } \end{array}

My idea:
\begin{array} { l } { \text { Since } \int _ { 0 } ^ { 1 } \frac { 1 } { x ^ { n } } d x \text { converges } } \\ { \text { if and only if } n < 1 \text { and } } \\ { \int _ { 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac { 1 } { x^n } d x \text { converyes if } } \\ { \text { and only if } n > 1 \text { , } } \\ { \text { (4) option is correct? } } \end{array}

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^n} \ \mathrm dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^n} \ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Is it existing?

Comment: You can try relating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^n} \ \mathrm dx$ to the $\zeta$ function.